# How do I update a row to be valid if the other columns match a certain DataType?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 5 rows. An ID column, 2 varchar columns, an isValid Column and a ValidationFailure column. The data for 2 columns are updated with data from an excelsheet through code. The data types while inserting for 2 columns are varchar. I now have to check if these 2 columns match MONEY type and if there is an issue update column isValid to false with ValidationFailure column a concatenation of the column names that fail the test.

I am using an update statement with a where clause. But I am unable to have a concatenation of the column names that fail the condition.

I am using the following update statement :

```
update t
set t.isValid = 0
from table t
where IsNumeric(t.col1+'e0') = 0 or IsNumeric(t.col2+'e0') = 0
```

How can I update t.ValidationFailure column with the column names that failed the condition?

If both fails then the column value can be col1,col2

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That update is product specific.)

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, not images.)  Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with a CASE

```
update t set
  t.isValid = 0,
  t.ValidationFailure = 
    case 
      when IsNumeric(t.col1+'e0') + IsNumeric(t.col2+'e0') = 0 then 'both'
      when IsNumeric(t.col1+'e0') = 0 then 'col1' 
      when IsNumeric(t.col2+'e0') = 0 then 'col2'
      else 'unknown'
    end
from table t 
where IsNumeric(t.col1+'e0') = 0 
  or IsNumeric(t.col2+'e0') = 0
```

Comment: What if both the columns are a failure? I will need to have both the columns names updated in ValidationFailure column. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why nested case expressions? One is enough.

Comment: That's much better!

Comment: This can work. But how will the performance be. I actually have 12 columns to check and probably 600+ records to check at a time How will the case statements affect the performance?

Comment: 600 rows is nothing. A simple `case` is not going to make the slightest difference in speed.

Comment: Hi . This is easier to write for 2 columns, but I have around 12. If I have to write every column the first statement wont be feasible. I mean, how can I write for combination of more than one failed columns in 12 ? The permutations and combinations are really high in that case

Comment: The areas that you should be looking into for handling a larger number of values, would be use bitwise to store multiple values in a single column. Attached link explains the workings. 

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1218/sql-server-bitwise-operators-to-store-multiple-values-in-one-column/